# Prevent minecraft realm griefing

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

My young son and a few of his friends have started playing minecraft together on their nintendo switches in a realm.
Because they're young (and still learning how to play nicely) they keep on destroying each others works and the whole thing ends in tears.

Is there any way to set up and protect their own areas/bases?  Or a rule that says only the person that placed a block can destroy it?

Comment: We had workaround for it with portals that could be used only by one person with command blocks in bedrock with button "execute as Perrin255 in minecraft:overworld run teleport 100000 64 -100000" and you can test if that player is exetuting it with another command block "execute if entity @p[x=123,y=64,z=234,distance=..2,name=Perrin255]"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, as far as I know. You could find a server that has grief-protected survival, but I'm not sure how to protect in realms, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own server and you want to prevent greifing just get a client that adds plots to your server so only the plot owner can break blocks,place blocks and interact with chest if you want detailed information on how to do this just go to YouTube but if your trying to prevent greifing on a realm then i have know idea how to do that sry